# Should a person console a coworker if he/she was fired?

Tags: termination, coworking

What is the etiquette if a coworker on your team was fired for poor performance and you are friends? Should you refrain from saying anything to the former coworker for some time?

Comment: If you are a friend. Sure.

Comment: Where and when would you say something? Still at the workplace before they leave?

Comment: Your question title asks "Should I console them" while your body asks "Should I refrain from talking to them". This can lead to confusion when people respond with a short answer such as "of course you should!". Try to keep the body of your question consistent with the title. You could say "Can I console them or should I refrain from talking to them" to make the question more consistent while asking what you want to ask

Comment: I think that a general principle to "treat others the way you want to be treated" applies in this situation as well.

Comment: @ljden I see that a lot. While it would be nice for the question asked to be consistent in the title and the body, I think answerers need to be clear on which question they are answering.

Comment: Agreed, although in this case the answer is clear (they quote the part they are answering) and it is the first comment reply to the question where the ambiguity arose... I read it as "Should you refrain from saying anything to the former coworker for some time? If you are a friend. Sure." and did a double take

Comment: Out of interest, why do you think it matters why they were fired? Let's say they did something really bad, they are still you friend.

Answer (score 51):

Absolutely. Being fired sucks, and they're likely to be upset and stressed out. Depending on their personal circumstances, they might also be really worried about what this means for their future: can they afford to pay their rent, can they support their dependents, how long will it take them to find a new job, etc.

If they're a friend, you should do what you can to support them. Maybe that's helping them search for a new job. Maybe it's giving them a good reference. Maybe it's just taking them out for a drink and letting them vent.

Just be careful that you don't say or do anything that'll come back and bite you. It's fine (and very understandable) for them to be pissed off, and venting about all the bad things about (and people at) their former job, or even thinking about some kind of retaliation. But that doesn't mean that *you* should start doing the same.

Comment: Do we know they were actually a friend?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie The OP seems to think they are.

Comment: @Barmar Cheers. I read it about 5 times to check and I still missed that.

Answer (score 28):

> Should you refrain from saying anything to the former coworker for sometime?

**No**, your co-worker being fired is not, on its own, a reason to shun them.

Comment: Giving someone space is not "shunning".

Comment: @Acccumulation The question is really ambiguous. It doesn't really make it clear if it means "should you avoid bringing up the subject of them being fired" (reasonable to let them lead the conversation) or "should you avoid interacting with them at all" (don't do that) or anything in between that.

Answer (score 17):

> What is the etiquette if a coworker on your team was fired for poor
> performance and you are friends?

The same etiquette as any embarrassing situation.  You attempt to avoid any further embarrassment, and allow them to grieve the loss of their job (should they care to do so).

Also, I wouldn't consider the reasons of the firing important.  Many companies fire for reasons they keep private with public announcements using completely different reasons (to position themselves better legally).  Performance might not mean productivity.  I've personally seen top performers fired for performance reasons, backed up by the dumbest reasoning possible, just so they could use the "magic words" that would create the least legal risk to the company.

> Should you refrain from saying anything to the former coworker for
> some time?

Normally no.  If your immediate conversation with your friend shows that they are still processing the hurt of termination, then you might need to give them time to heal, but you shouldn't alter the friendship just because they were fired.

**Consider the kind of friendship you have**

Your friend might be one of

- Lifelong Friends - A friend you've shared significant history with.
- Best Friends - Your best close friend.
- Close Friends - A friend you can safely share your faults with.
- Social Group Friends - A non-Close Friend in one of your social groups.
- Activity Friends - A friend tied to a specific leisure activity.
- Friends of Convenience - Friends who share in your tasks or duties.
- Acquaintance Friends - People you encounter frequently, who lack shared duties, lack shared activities, lack shared social groups, lack shared history, and lack detailed knowledge of your faults.

Most coworkers are **Acquaintance Friends**, but your friend might be more.

Assuming you have one of the non-Acquaintance Friendship patterns in place, fall back on that pattern.  If you only have an Acquaintance Friendship, you can explore shifting the friendship, but it is easier said than done.

**If your friend is grieving, treat the firing like a grieving event**

For some, being fired is like a death of an opportunity.  If your friend is reacting this way, expect the friend to go through a grieving process.

Good ways to support grieving friends:

- Be supportive, but don't try to fix things.
- Be open to talking / hearing about feelings.
- Be non-active, avoid telling them what to do.
- Be ready to admit you can't make it better.
- Be careful to not ask them for actions.
- Be careful to not ask them to change their feelings.
- Recognize their loss.
- Don't put time limits on anything.

Bad ways to support them:

- Help them fix the loss.
- Focus on your discomfort.
- Tell them what they need to do.
- Reason with them about the termination.
- Explain why they lost the job.
- Decide if the termination was just or unjust.
- Make the termination seem like less of a blow.
- Push them to get over the loss or move on.

Comment: +1 for it depending on the type of friendship

Comment: And unless you are ready to consider that as a gift rather than a loan, don't loan them any money. Unless you are ready to have them live with you for years, don't offer your couch or spare bedroom.

Answer (score 7):

**Do what's best for your friend**

Typically friends help, support, and console each other if something bad happens, the same way they celebrate together if something good happens.

What that might be, depends on your friend. Some people like to be left alone to digest for a while, some people need to let of steam so a sympathetic ear to rant to is good, some people may want a distraction, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The "right thing to do" is to console your friend, but that needs a qualification in this instance.

You might need to check your company handbook to see what the rules are for this situation. Some companies have very strict rules about contacting former employees. I've worked places where someone being fired wasn't allowed to talk to anyone and others weren't allowed to talk to them while they immediately cleared out their desk, under supervision, and was walked out the door.

Granted, that could have been a specific case that I didn't have background info on, but it's not unheard of in other companies.

Another company I worked for fired me for not hitting all the probationary metrics. They escorted me to a conference room to tell me this and escorted me to the door where I found a manager holding a bag of all my desk items waiting for me.

Again, that was not normal policy for most places I've worked.

Some places put [strict rules](https://newschannel9.com/news/local/can-your-employer-order-you-not-to-talk-to-a-co-worker-off-the-clock) on discussing the company or the work outside of the company's walls, especially with people not employed by the company. Some of this is intellectual property rights related, other instances is paranoia, and some cases is pure narcissism. Looking in your employee handbook, talking to your manager, or asking HR might not be a bad start. If there are policies in place, follow them or you might be out the door too, unfortunately.

> Unfortunately, the answer to the question you ask is Yes. A company is free to use poor business judgment and terminate an employee because he or she is doing something outside of work that the employer just doesn't happen to like. This will continue to be the case as long as employees/voters accept the "at-will" protections currently given to companies in Texas.

https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/can-an-employee-be-fired-for-talking-to-a-former-e-570032.html

> In an at will work relationship an employer has great discretion in setting the terms of employment. It can hire/fire, promote/demote, increase/decrease salary/hours, and impose just about whatever other conditions that is sees fit. This wouldinclude[sic] banning an employee from contacting an ex-employee.

https://www.freeadvice.com/legal/is-it-legal-for-an-employ-79231/

Most places, though, will not have a problem with you talking to your friend. It might even be common place for people to send "short timers" private email messages, or even group/team messages while at work. You probably don't want to go over and sit at their desk for a long period talking about the situation, since that can get you in trouble about not doing your own work.

Some places might even have a team outing to "send them off" at a bar or restaurant. Often, this is offsite so everyone can people can complain about the company/work/management/etc. without anyone hearing.

And privately, individually talking to your friend outside the workplace is fine, when not explicitly forbidden by your company.

Comment: "individually talking to your friend outside the workplace is fine, **when not explicitly forbidden by your company**." - I'm trying to think of a country where a company would be able to legally enforce this.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, businesses can prohibit employees from talking to each other off the clock, they can do other shady practices. https://newschannel9.com/news/local/can-your-employer-order-you-not-to-talk-to-a-co-worker-off-the-clock And it's not necessarily that it can be enforced, but drowning someone in legal fees and dragging them through political and social mud while doing it is more than enough to keep most people in check. https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/can-an-employee-be-fired-for-talking-to-a-former-e-570032.html and https://www.freeadvice.com/legal/is-it-legal-for-an-employ-79231/

Comment: Fortunately I live in a country (UK) where we have employment laws and a fair justice system. Employees can go to an Employment Tribunal without paying any fees.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I would love for that to be the case in the USA. Unions spent decades getting us what few protections workers now have and corporations have been trying to destroy the Unions and their progress for the past 20+ years, often successfully.

Comment: I have turned down more than one employment offer from the USA, for a variety of reasons, and the lack of worker's rights was one of them.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I've turned down a handful of jobs as soon as the interview was over, because of how they openly and badly treated their employees. It's so prevalent to treat employees badly that many companies even put it in their job descriptions. As if somehow working 60+ hours in a constantly "house on fire" pace for the industry standard, or lower, pay rate of 40 hrs per week is just insane, yet people call it "job security". I call it a short trip to the grave, or a therapists couch at best.

Comment: I don't want you to think everything is just perfect for workers here in the UK, our bosses are prone to the same failings as elsewhere, but at least the workers don't have to fight with both hands tied behind their backs.